# Interval comparison not working with if-statement - python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working on a bit of code that would allow me to fill a dataframe with specific strings or values depending on the index value and stock everything in a `dict`.
As a test, I wanted to fill a dataframe `df` with `'foo'` if the index was **less or equal to 3** or **greater or equal to 7**.

I thought the script I wrote bellow would work but it doesn't and I am afraid I am running out of ideas as to why.

```py
letter_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

mydict = dict()

for letter in letter_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = df.reindex(range(10))

    for i in df.index.astype(float):
        if i <= 3 or i >= 7:        
            df['toto'] = 'foo'

        else:
            df['toto'] = 'booo'

    mydict[letter] = dict()
    mydict[letter]['toto']  = df.toto
```

The output of this gives me:

```py
{'A1': {'toto': 0    foo
  1    foo
  2    foo
  3    foo
  4    foo
  5    foo
  6    foo
  7    foo
  8    foo
  9    foo
  Name: toto, dtype: object}}
```

Instead of:

```py
{'a': {'toto': 0    foo
  1    foo
  2    foo
  3    foo
  4    booo
  5    booo
  6    booo
  7    foo
  8    foo
  9    foo
  Name: toto, dtype: object}}
```

I thought of replacing `if i <= 3 or i >= 7:` with `if 3 <= i <= 7:` but I still get the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why cast it to float? The index should be integer type already, and can be directly compared to 3 and 7.

Comment: You aren't assigning to `df['toto'][i]`. The comparison is fine; you are just performing the same blanket assignment repeatedly.

Comment: `df['toto']` assign to the whole column. So you're assigning to the whole column 10 times, and you end up with the last assignment (which is `'foo'`).

Comment: I now understand what was wrong with my code (which was actually quite obvious I'm ashamed...) thank you very much for your help. @chepner

Comment: @00 I actualy casted to float as a test since ```df.index``` wasn't working. Thank you very much for your input I made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said, df['toto'] assign to the whole column. You will have to iterate over rows. Try this :

```
letter_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

mydict = dict()

for letter in letter_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = df.reindex(range(10))
    df['toto'] = ''

    for i in df.index:
        if i <= 3 or i >= 7:
            df['toto'][i] = 'foo'
        else:
            df['toto'][i] = 'booo'

    mydict[letter] = dict()
    mydict[letter]['toto']  = df.toto
```

Output :

```
{'a': {'toto': 0     foo
  1     foo
  2     foo
  3     foo
  4    booo
  5    booo
  6    booo
  7     foo
  8     foo
  9     foo
  Name: toto, dtype: object}, 'b': {'toto': 0     foo
  1     foo
  2     foo
  3     foo
  4    booo
  5    booo
  6    booo
  7     foo
  8     foo
  9     foo
  Name: toto, dtype: object}, 'c': {'toto': 0     foo
  1     foo
  2     foo
  3     foo
  4    booo
  5    booo
  6    booo
  7     foo
  8     foo
  9     foo
  Name: toto, dtype: object}}
```